# Field of type contact

Tags: component, custom-component, form-fields-types, com-contacts

In a form of a custom component, how can I add field of type `contact` instead of type `user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `modal_contact` field type from `com_contact`.

```
    <field 
        name="example"
        type="modal_contact"
        addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_contact/models/fields"
    />
```